# Test Case to make sure data cannot be loaded

Tags: java, junit, testcase

I have a test case I'm trying to finish.  It should try to find location ABC, but that doesn't actually exist in the DB.  Essentially, it should not load the data I'm trying to find.  I've tried a bunch of things, and haven't figured it out yet.  Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void testFindByInvalidLocABC() {
    System.out.println("findByInvalidLocABC");
    Storage result = StorageFacadeTest.facade.findByLoc("ABC");
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals("NOK-0000001402", result.getId());
    assertEquals("ABC", result.getLoc());
}
```

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If "ABC" should not be in database then `result` most likely should be null and you need to do `assertNull(result);`.

Comment: That implementation looks like the opposite of testing for an invalid value. What is the desired behavior of findByLoc when it cannot find the data? return null or something else?

Comment: I suppose the class under test is named `StorageFacade`.  How is it *supposed* to respond when the requested data are not found?  This should be documented.  Your test case should verify that it indeed behaves as documented.  The behavior you are asserting looks ... odd ... for such a case.

Comment: First, I'm not even sure what it should do when it cannot find the data.  I'm just going to say that it should print something like "ABC is not a valid location."

Second, I'm basing this test off of a previous test that passes:
public void testFindByLoc() {        
        System.out.println("findByLoc");
        Storage result = StorageFacadeTest.facade.findByLoc("BIN3");
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals("NOK-0000001402", result.getId());
        assertEquals("BIN3", result.getLoc());
    }

If you think I should code this differently, let me know.

Comment: May I suggest you look up on naming test cases. It would be better if your tests read like documentation, something like "whenSearchingByInvalidLoc_ShouldReturnNull" for example. The test name does not necessarily have to match the name of the method under test, rather the class' behavior (although for a well designed interface that is usually the case).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a test case I'm trying to finish. It should try to find
>   location ABC, but that doesn't actually exist in the DB

To ensure that data be present or not present during test executions, you cannot rely on a applicative or shared database.
**Automated tests have to be repeatable**. Otherwise, these will be reliable today but useless and error prone tomorrow.
So I encourage you to clean/populate a test database( or schema) before the tests be executed.

Besides, as others commented, your test doesn't look like a "not found" scenario. You assert the retrieved `Storage` content. It makes no sense.
It should rather look like :

```
@Test
public void findByLoc_with_invalidLoc_returns_null() {
    Storage result = StorageFacadeTest.facade.findByLoc("ABC");
    assertNull(result);
}
```

Some improvements for your unit test:

1) Returning `Optional` instead of `null` in the method under test is probably better but you don't use it in your actual implementation. So I follow it in my example.

2) `System.out` is really not advised in the test code.

3) The `test` prefix in the test method is not advised either. It is a legacy way as Java annotations didn't exist.

Comment: When I change my code to that, I get an error saying: No entity found for query.

Comment: "No entity found for query" means that you use `em.getSingleResult()`  method. In your unit test you can specify in the method declaration that you expect NoResultException thown : `@Test(expected=NoResultException.class)`

Comment: I added the JPA tag in your question. Showing the implementation code would be a good idea too.